# Dropzone.js what is the difference between "success" and "complete"?

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js and want to clear the images and form data once the image has been uploaded and my PHP backend code completely finishes processing and returns (I think this is when the check mark appears at the bottom of the image?).

Using Dropzone.js there is both a:

```
this.on("success", function(file, responseText)

this.on("complete", function(file, responseText)
```

is the "success" when the backend upload.php finishes and returns the result (the check mark appears at the bottom of the image) and the "complete" when the file has uploaded to the backend host (the progress bar completes) and upload.php starts to process the uploaded image file?

Thanks for advice and explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list):

- `success` -   The file has been uploaded *successfully*. Gets the server response as second argument. (This event was called `finished` previously)
- `complete` - Called when the upload was *either successful or erroneous*.